# Can't Access Graylog after Deploying Charmed Distribution of Kubernetes with Logging

Tags: apache2, juju, conjure-up, kubernetes

I started with conjure-up but never got the summary screen with all the endpoints.

I do not know how to access graylog. I tried hitting the ip for Apache2 but that showed me some sort of Apache welcome screen for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access it in the browser at `https://graylog-machine-ip:9000`